# Can't retrieve file name from a mega link

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape info from mega links, I used BeautifulSoup and was able to retrieve file sizes and folder counts (mostly but not everytime though). But for some reason I don't quite understand, the output does not include file or folder names. I am trying to retrieve the name of main folder and the code I tried is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link="MEGALINK"
url = f"{link}"   
page = urlopen(url)
page=page.read()
html = page.decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup
```

I also looked for mega.py library but don't think it is of any use...

Comment: What's a `MEGALINK`?

Comment: Mega heavily utilize JS. Use Selenium instead.

Comment: "MEGALINK" is any mega.nz link, I didn't share a link for copyright issues

Answer (score 0):

As mega.nz heavily uses javascript, i will use Selenium to scrape:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(MEGALINK)
time.sleep(5)
```

now the page is loaded into your browser, Firefox, with geckoDriver. You can use Chrome/Edge too. Now, you can selectors like `find_element_by_class` or `find_element_by_xpath` to select elements and scrape.